# Kafka Streams StreamsException when I work with multiple streams

Tags: kotlin, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, spring-kafka

I'm working with Kafka Streams & Kotlin to develop a service that has streams for three topics. The first one has an Avro value and the other two have String values.

In my `properties` file, I have `SpecificAvroSerde` as a default value Serde, and then I use `Consumed.with(Serdes.String(), Serdes.String())` to consume the String values.

```
    val topicOneStream = streamsBuilder.stream<String, AvroObject>(topicOne)
        .peek { k, _ -> logger.info("Received message with key: $k") }
        .flatMapValues { v -> listOf(v) }.groupByKey().reduce { v1, _ -> v1 }

    val topicTwoStream = streamsBuilder
        .stream<String, String>(topicTwo, Consumed.with(Serdes.String(), Serdes.String()))
        .peek { k, _ -> logger.info("Received message with key: $k") }
        .flatMapValues { v -> listOf(v) }.groupByKey().reduce { v1, _ -> v1 }

    val topicThreeStream = streamsBuilder.stream<String, String>(topicThree, Consumed.with(Serdes.String(), Serdes.String()))
        .peek { k, _ -> logger.info("Received message with key: $k") }
        .mapValues { v -> objectMapper.readValue(v, AdviceCreated::class.java) }
        .flatMapValues { v -> listOf(v) }.groupByKey().reduce { v1, _ -> v1 }
```

When I have the configuration of the following stream as default for values, I see that Avro stream (the first one) is working fine and consume what I'm publishing on that topic. But I get an exception when I publish to the string value streams using the same configuration.

```
default.value.serde: io.confluent.kafka.streams.serdes.avro.SpecificAvroSerde
```

Here is the Exception from publishing to the topicTwo and topicThree:

```
org.apache.kafka.streams.errors.StreamsException: A serializer (io.confluent.kafka.streams.serdes.avro.SpecificAvroSerializer) is not compatible to the actual value type (value type: java.lang.String). Change the default Serdes in StreamConfig or provide correct Serdes via method parameters.
```

PS. It has to be three streams in the same service because there will be a join later on.

Comment: Your code looks correct. Can you reproduce the issue using the `TopologyTestDriver`?

Comment: I have written a test for it using TopologyTestDriver, it will show the same error. If `SpecificAvroSerde` is default string streams won't be consumed, but if `StringSerde` is the default then avro stream won't consume!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to a friend (Mario Boikov), the problem happens when Kafka does the grouping to produce a new `KTable`. It doesn't know which serializer to take for the grouping, so it takes the default Serde for value, which is in my case `SpecificAvroSerde`

It was solved by providing groupByKey with the serializer it needs for the grouping:

```
val topicTwoStream = streamsBuilder
    .stream<String, String>(topicTwo, Consumed.with(Serdes.String(), Serdes.String()))
    .peek { k, _ -> logger.info("Received message with key: $k") }
    .flatMapValues { v -> listOf(v) }.groupByKey(Grouped.with(Serdes.String(), Serdes.String())).reduce { v1, _ -> v1 }

val topicThreeStream = streamsBuilder.stream<String, String>(topicThree, Consumed.with(Serdes.String(), Serdes.String()))
    .peek { k, _ -> logger.info("Received message with key: $k") }
    .flatMapValues { v -> listOf(v) }.groupByKey(Grouped.with(Serdes.String(), Serdes.String())).reduce { v1, _ -> v1 }
    .mapValues { v -> objectMapper.readValue(v, AdviceCreated::class.java) }
```

Cheers